# import a specific line from a text file into a SQL DB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Is there anyway to import a specific line from a text file into an MS SQL database.  The data I am after is the third line from the bottom from the text file and it will be the same each time.

Comment: Use BULK INSERT into a temporary table and then extract the line you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to access the text file, then write a code to INSERT it into your database file. Maybe if you add what you have done so far, i might be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

You can import whole text file from SQL Server Management Studio Import Data Wizard.

Right Click on your Database - Select Task - Import Data

Select source as **Flat File**.
Every line in text file is treated as a new row in table in which data is imported.